# How to run script with custom global context in Firefox chrome?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am trying to create extension which work with DOM of some web pages.

I have a code:

```
document.getElementById("appcontent").addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    _this._onPageLoad(e);
}, true);
```

But in _onPageLoad function my global context is global window (ChromeWindow), not a window with my webpage. How do I can run _onPageLoad with global context of window where event was fired (webpage) and pass arguments here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, overlay scripts run in the context of the top-level window, i.e. the `ChromeWindow`.

However, you *somewhat* simulate another context.

```
_this._onPageLoad = function(window, document, e) {
  // Called as .call(window, window, window.document, e);
  // this === window === <content window>
  // document === <content document>
}; 

document.getElementById("appcontent").addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
    let win = e.originalTarget;
    if (win.ownerDocument) {
      win = win.ownerDocument;
    }
    if (win.defaultView) {
      win = win.defaultView;
    }
    _this._onPageLoad.call(win, win, win.document, e);
}, true);
```

This would call your `_onPageLoad` with a proper `this`, `window` and `document` belonging to the document that the event indicates the load of. 
This scheme will not really reset the global, however, so `addEventListener` would still refer to the top-level window. Also, the script would not run in a sandbox, and would still have full privileges. So in the end, this just adds a bit more convenience.

It would also be possible to set up and use a real [`Sandbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.Sandbox), however that is kind of complicated.
The basic idea would be to choose the appropriate principal (fully privileged, or content-privilged), constructing a sandbox and supplying the content window as the `sandboxPrototype` and the calling `.evalInSandbox(...)`. This is more or less what the `SDK` does internally for content scripts... However, this is usually overkill unless you need a real and proper security boundary (e.g. need to execute user-provided or remote scripts).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I neef to run userscripts.
Now I am trying to understand how Sandbox working, but as I understand the only one way to run my script in Sandbox - convert it to String :(
And also I have a problem with Zepto library which was included in ChromWindow and must be passed to webpage.

Comment: Sounds like you might be better off using SDK and its content scripts (`page-mod`) instead of re-inventing the stuff yourself in a XUL-overlay add-on.

Comment: Unfortunately page-mod is inconvenient for me.

Comment: Regarding your "only strings" comment: Actually you can "import" stuff into the sandbox. See the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.Sandbox#Importing_functions_or_objects_into_the_sandbox). Also consider reading the Greasemonkey and/or Scriptish code both of which set up content-privileged Sandboxes but also "import" chrome-privileged API functions into the boxes.  (Disclosure: I'm contributed to Scriptish)

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
Lpr2.prototype._evalInSandbox = function(script, doc, data) {
    var sandbox = new Components.utils.Sandbox(doc.defaultView);
    sandbox.unsafeWindow = doc.defaultView.window.wrappedJSObject;
    sandbox.window = doc.defaultView.window;
    sandbox.document = sandbox.window.document;
    sandbox.__proto__ = sandbox.window;
    var functionName = 'execute_' + script.name;
    var functionText = 'function ' + functionName + script.run.toString().substring(8);
    functionText += '; window.lpr2data = ' + JSON.stringify(data) + '; ' + functionName + '(window, document, Zepto);';
    Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript('chrome://*/content/lib/zepto.min.js', sandbox, 'UTF–8');
    Components.utils.evalInSandbox(functionText, sandbox);
}
```

Bad, but this is only one working solutuion for me.